# Is it better to access several times a value at array[i] or to stock this value in a variable (v=array[i]) and access this variable v instead?

Tags: java, arrays, cost-based-optimizer

I'd like to know if it costs more to access several times a value at array[i] or  to stock the value as a new variable (v=array[i]) and access the variable v several times instead ?

for example (in java), would it be better to write :

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5};

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if (array[i]<0){
        System.out.println("negativ");
    }else if(array[i]>0){
        System.out.println("positiv");
        if (array[i]==42){
            System.out.println("great answer");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("zero");
    }
}
```

or

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
int v;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    v = array[i];
    if (v<0){
        System.out.println("negativ");
    }else if(v>0){
        System.out.println("positiv");
        if (v==42){
            System.out.println("great answer");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("zero");
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It isn't better or worse. Prefer whichever you find most readable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it doesn't affect the cost to use one way or an other ?

Answer (score 1):

You end up taking two more bytes with the second form:

```
  34: istore_2
  35: iload_2
```

Variable access ends up being an iaload vs an iload_2 - not a huge difference. If you had enough variables (more than 4) that you had to use iload (index) rather than iload_ then you would see even larger code for the second form.

To be explicit: you don't save anything by introducing the variable, and in fact add instructions (where the variable gets set).

Answer (score 0):

Both the styles have their pros and cons
For `array[i]` access it might be little cumbersome to read but is a **safer** bet. In your example you are only *reading* from the array, think of a case where you have to *write* as well. You might end up updating just `v` and that might prove to be a quite costly bug !!

Another point to note is your example is about *primitive* array hence the storage/access overhead I guess is pretty negligible

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, this has been very helpful :-)

Comment: Glad that it helped you - would you mind accepting/up voting it - might help others reaching here with the same question

Comment: I tried to up vote it but I don't have enough of reputation for my votes to be counted yet (sorry). I'll come back once I'll get some :-)

Answer (score 0):

Neither. The java language has the enhanced for loops optimization for this:

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5};

for(int v: array){
    if (v<0){
        System.out.println("negativ");
    }else if(v>0){
        System.out.println("positiv");
        if (v==42){
            System.out.println("great answer");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("zero");
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int v: arrays)` should be `for(int v: array)`

Comment: the loop was not the question.. it was variable assignment and usage

Comment: The variable is set in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will optimize both to the same thing so it makes no difference. Prefer the most readable.

Comment: @Tom Oops, missed that :-|